# $f\in C[-\infty,\infty]\,\land\,f(f(x))=-x$ Is there such a $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> $f\in C[-\infty,\infty]\,\land\,f(f(x))=-x$ Is there such a $f$?

Let $h=f\circ f$, then $h(x)+h(-x)=0\Rightarrow h(-x)=-h(x)\Rightarrow h$ is odd.

But what should I do next?

Comment: $h$ is odd if $h(-x) = -h(x)$. So $f\circ f$ is not odd.

Comment: Ah ha!! Now I am stupid @@!

Comment: @John Haha... we all are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function.

Assume $f$ satisfies the desired condition. Then $f$ is clearly injective, and since it is continuous, we conclude it is *monotone*. But the composition of a monotone function with itself must be increasing.